# How to filter a column to select particular keyword

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table called Products in which I have a column called product and airport.
Airports has Multiple values
I  need a SQL statement by which I will be able to get products names for one airport from the column airport (Which has multiple values such as Birmingham International, Luton Airport, Heathrow, Gatwick)
e.g. If I want all the products for the airport Heathrow, How would I do that? 
would I use indexes,  if yes, how?
Here is the sample data:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM products order by product;

| id | product                          | price  | description                    | type    | airport                                                    |
|  1 | Benson and Hedges Special filter | £28.00 | Cigarettes, Lighter and filter | Tobacco | Birmingham International, Luton Airport, Heathrow, Gatwick |
-----------------------
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Some sample data and expected output would help clarify your question.

Comment: Can you add same sample output and table values

Comment: So here I want something like select product where airport="Birmingham "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create new table for Airports, f.e.

```
CREATE TABLE "AIRPORT"
  (
    "AIRPORT_ID"    NUMBER ,
    "AIRPORT_NAME"   CHAR
)
```

and link your table with AIRPORT through link-table

```
CREATE TABLE "CITS_USER"."L_YOUR_TABLE_AIRPORT"
  (
    "L_YOUR_TABLE_AIRPORT_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "YOUR_TABLE_ID"          NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "AIRPORT_ID"       NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE
    CONSTRAINT "FK_L_YOUR_TABLE_AIRPORT_YOUR_TABLE" FOREIGN KEY ("YOUR_TABLE_ID") REFERENCES "YOUR_TABLE" ("YOUR_TABLE_ID") ENABLE,
    CONSTRAINT "FK_L_L_YOUR_TABLE_AIRPORT_AIRPORT" FOREIGN KEY ("AIRPORT_ID") REFERENCES "AIRPORT" ("AIRPORT_ID") ENABLE
  )
```

so your query will be

```
select yt.product from 
your_table yt
join L_YOUR_TABLE_AIRPORT yta on yta.YOUR_TABLE_ID = yt.YOUR_TABLE_ID
join AIRPORT ap on ap.AIRPORT_ID = yta.AIRPORT_ID
where ap.NAME = 'Luton Airport'
```

Answer (score 0):

### Structure change

I would suggest that you create other tables this way:

```
Product (id, product, price, description)
ProductAirports (productId, airportId)
Airport (id, name)
```

### the query

Then, if you want the products available in the air port of Birmingham International you would write

```
select 
    p.id, p.product
from Product p
    inner join ProductAirports pa on pa.productId = p.id
    inner join Airport a on a.id = pa.airportId
where
    a.name = 'Birmingham International'
```